# Stars in checkboxlist using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, checkboxlist

I am using a jQuery plugin which convert 2.0 3.0 into 2 star images or 3 star images using by manipulating css of a `div`.

jQuery code for this is

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $('span.stars').stars();    

        });

        $.fn.stars = function () {
            return $(this).each(function () {
                $(this).html($('<span />').width(Math.max(0, (Math.min(5, parseFloat($(this).html())))) * 16));
            });
        }
</script>
```

and css for this is

```
span.stars, span.stars span
{
    display: block;
    background: url(../../Images/star.png) 0 -16px repeat-x;
    width: 80px;
    height: 16px;
}
span.stars span
{
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

But now I want to apply this in checkbox list but I am not getting the right way to do this.

My checkboxlist is as follow :

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chbStars" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="chbStars_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1.0">    </asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2.0">    </asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3.0">    </asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="4.0">    </asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="5" Value="5.0">    </asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

i tried this by manipulating the css like this

```
#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chbStars label
{

    background: url(../../Images/star.png) 0 -16px repeat-x;
    width: 80px;
    height: 16px;
}

#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chbStars  span
{
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

But I am not getting the right way to change jQuery?

Any direction will help a lot to me.

For span the rendered HTML is

```
<span style="width: 32px;"></span>
```

And for checkboxlist the rendered HTML is

```
<table border="0" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chbStars">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$chbStars$0\',\'\')', 0)" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$chbStars$0" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chbStars_0"><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chbStars_0">1</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$chbStars$1\',\'\')', 0)" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$chbStars$1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chbStars_1"><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chbStars_1">2</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$chbStars$2\',\'\')', 0)" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$chbStars$2" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chbStars_2"><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chbStars_2">3</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$chbStars$3\',\'\')', 0)" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$chbStars$3" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chbStars_3"><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chbStars_3">4</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$chbStars$4\',\'\')', 0)" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$chbStars$4" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chbStars_4"><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chbStars_4">5</label></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: the generated html code would be helpful ..

Comment: @remy which one for span or for checkbox list

Comment: for checkboxlist, or even both ;)

Comment: the span HTML seems to be incomplete ...

Answer (score 0):

1. you have to change the jQuery selector to something like  `$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chbStars label').stars();`
2. you have to adjust the .css, #ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chbStars label to span

i hope this will display you something, the selection via checkbox needs to be coded ..